# MongoDB: How to replace object inside array with new object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I have a simple question about node and mongodb. I am using the provided node mongodb driver, not mongoose. I have something like this in a collection of my database:

```
{
   accounts: [
     {username: "", id: "", property: value},
     {username: "", id: "", property: value} 
   ]
}
```

I want to replace the object inside the accounts array that has a specific id value with another object. How would I be able to do that?

**NOTE:** I know you might say this is a duplicate, but I have tried a lot of things and for some reason they don't work, and I feel that even though people say it should work, I am doing something wrong. I am an amateur and I code just for fun, so don't expect a lot, and please take two minutes to write a simple response. Thank you!

Comment: have you tried with `$elemMatch` ?https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

Comment: Never Mind! Figured it out!!!! Thanks so much though @Yogesh